# Index error in function calculating median

Tags: python, function

I'm writing a function to calculate median and getting IndexError:

```
def median(median):
    median.sort()
    if len(median) % 2 != 0:
        b = math.floor(len(median))
        return median[b]
    else:
        return (median[len(median)] + median[len(median)-1])/2



    p = [5,2,6,1,2,6]
print('Student median: ' + str(median(p)))
```

How should I make it properly?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to divide the index by 2 to get the middle position

The corrected code:

```
def median(median):
    median.sort()
    if len(median) % 2 != 0:
        return median[int(len(median)/2)]
    else:
        return (median[int(len(median)/2)] + median[int((len(median)-1)/2)])/2

p = [5,2,6,1,2,6]

print('Student median: ' + str(median(p)))
```

Outputs:

```
Student median: 3.5
```